# How do I create a lazy var for an NSPredicate that can return nil

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3, nspredicate

I have a `UITableView` that can be filtered and sorted. When the user selects a filter option I'm trying to use a `lazy var` called `liftUuidPredicate` to construct the predicate. The user's selection is stored in `UserDefaults` but if there is no filter selected, there won't be any value in `UserDefaults.logFilterLiftUuid()` and this is causing my app to crash with an error:

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -copyWithZone: cannot be
>   sent to an abstract object of class NSPredicate: Create a concrete
>   instance!

Clearly I need to create a concrete instance of NSPredicate, but I don't know how to do this when there is no predicate.

```
// throws the 'Create a concrete instance' error
lazy var liftUuidPredicate: NSPredicate = {
    guard let liftUuid = UserDefaults.logFilterLiftUuid() else { return NSPredicate() }

    return NSPredicate(format: "uuid = %@", liftUuid)
}()

// fetchedResultsController
func fetchLiftEvents() -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> {
  let moc = stack.managedObjectContext
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "LiftEvent")

  fetchRequest.predicate = liftUuidPredicate
  if let sortBy = UserDefaults.logSortSelection() {fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: sortBy, ascending: false)]}

  fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

  do {
       try fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
      } catch {
       fatalError("Unable to fetch Lift Events: \(error)")
    }
  return fetchedResultsController!
}
```

The available methods of `NSPredicate()` expect a format and some form of argument(s) which won't work when I want there to be no predicate. In the `guard let` statement, I also tried `return NSPredicate(value: false)` but, as I expected the fetchRequest then returned no records.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSPredicate` is an abstract class.  You can't have an `NSPredicate()`, you must instantiate it with the required info to get a concrete instance.

The key is to change the type of `liftUuidPredicate` from `NSPredicate` to `NSPredicate?` and instead of returning `NSPredicate()` return `nil` if the `guard` fails.

I added some boiler plate code to make my snippet compile so you will want to change that as your needs dictate.

```
`extension UserDefaults {

    class func logFilterLiftUuid() -> String? {
        return "bar"
    }

    class func logSortSelection() -> String? {
        return "bar"
    }

}

class Foo {

    let stack = NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject>()
    var fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>()
    // throws the 'Create a concrete instance' error
    lazy var liftUuidPredicate: NSPredicate? = {
        guard let liftUuid = UserDefaults.logFilterLiftUuid() else { return nil }

        return NSPredicate(format: "uuid = %@", liftUuid)
    }()

    // fetchedResultsController
    func fetchLiftEvents() -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> {
        let moc = stack.managedObjectContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "LiftEvent")

        fetchRequest.predicate = liftUuidPredicate
        if let sortBy = UserDefaults.logSortSelection() {fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: sortBy, ascending: false)]}

        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Unable to fetch Lift Events: \(error)")
        }
        return fetchedResultsController
    }

}
```